# remove unnecessary variables in joomla routing

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

Presently my url is :- **http://192.168.1.102/joomla25/index.php/component/component_name/view_name/1/info/normal**

But i want only the format :- `http://192.168.1.102/joomla25/normal`

what is the technique to do that by using joomla router.php file? pls help....

my code is:---

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     $Id: router.php 21389 2011-05-26 17:28:26Z dextercowley $
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2011 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights         reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * @param   array
 * @return  array
 */


function ComponentNameBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

    if(isset($query['view']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
        unset($query['view']);
    }

    if( isset($query['id']) )
    {
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset( $query['id'] );
    }
    if(isset($query['tab']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['tab'];
        unset($query['tab']);
    }
    if(isset( $query['pt'] ))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['pt'];
        unset( $query['pt'] );
    }

   //unset( $query['view'] );
   return $segments;
}

function ComponentNameParseRoute($segments)
{
   $vars = array();
   $app =& JFactory::getApplication();
   $menu =& $app->getMenu();
   $item =& $menu->getActive();
   // Count segments

   $count = count( $segments );

   //Handle View and Identifier
   switch( $segments[0] )
   {
        case 'pdetails':
            $vars['view'] = 'pdetails'; 
            $id = explode(':', $segments[1]);
            $tab = explode(':', $segments[2]);
            $pt = explode(':', $segments[3]);

            $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
            $vars['tab'] = $tab[0];
            $vars['pt'] = $pt[0];
            break;
   }

   return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue with a custom developed component. So what I did to resolve the issue is that created a menu item and then in my component code which I use to create link ie the **Jroute()** rather then giving

```
index.php?option=blabla&view=blabla
```

I did tried

```
 index.php?Item=<menuitemid>.
```

In this way I build the route to my component and then in my component router's parseroute I mentioned the other condition ($vars) which was needed. The main thing was that I got it diverted to my component so i have my own parseroute here in which I can mention the correct route for it.

I hope it will help some one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your admin, click on Global Configuration in the Site menu. It should default to the Site tab, if not then click on the Site tab. Find the SEO Settings and make sure you have Search Engine Friendly URLs, Use URL Rewriting, Adds Suffix to URL all turned on (set to yes). Then you need to located the file htaccess.txt in the Joomla root directory and rename it to `.htaccess`. that should fix your URLs.

Comment: My boss said me dont use .htaccess file.... It should be done only through router.php file. So i am searching for that.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time rewriting URLs without htaccess. It's also a really bad idea to hack the core, you will have problems every time there is an update.

Comment: I am not hacking the code. I have done it by using ItemId(which comes with menu item). But I have lot of items in my component to display...so I cant create so many menu items. So i have to solve this without creating menu item.

Comment: Is there a reason your boss doesn't want to use htaccess? Using the itemid is just compensating for rewriting the URL, which is trivially easy and would allow you to create the URLs you want with ease.

Comment: I dont know the reason...i think client asked him to do it like that. But without itemid we cant do any thing for this. I am trying to do it without using itemid.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do it your way without itemid. This is one of those time you need to make a recommendation as the expert. You have spent a lot of time on something that should have taken no more than 2 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

I would use an extension for that, for example sh404sef or any other SEF extension.

Answer (score -1):

What will say your boss when you'll need to upgrade your Joomla version? All your modifications will be lost and you'll have to recreate all.

Just use SEF component like sh404sef or insert one line of code in your htaccess to have some nice url!